# JPA Annotation issue

Tags: java, jpa, annotations

I have a Table A , Table AB , TABLE B , Table AB has foreign key references to Table A and Table B. There is a One to One relation between Table A and Table AB.and Many to one between Table B and Table AB.

My question is if i am saving domain for table B, it is saving data in table AB but not in A Please let me know if this is the expected behavior or can i save all data in all other tables just by calling save on Object B

```
Class A
{
    @OneToOne(mappedBy="abpk.a")
    @Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL,
               org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN })
    private AB ab;
}

@Entity
@AssociationOverrides({
@AssociationOverride(name = "abpk.a", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "colA", referencedColumnName = "colA")),
@AssociationOverride(name = "abpk.b", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "Colb", referencedColumnName = "colB")) })
Class AB
{
    ABPK abpk = new ABPK();
    A a;
    B b;

    //inner class
    class ABPK
    {
       A a;
       B b;

       @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
       @Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL, 
                  org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN })
       @JoinColumn(name="b")
       //Getter for A
       GetA();

       @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
       //Getter for B
       GetB();
     }
}

Class B
{
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "abpk.b")
    @Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL,
               org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE_ORPHAN })
    private List<AB> abList;
}
```

Comment: So do u think i need to add cascading on both sides of the relation?

Comment: ideally, it should be enough to set cascading on the owning side. But wire both sides of the relationship anyway.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on how you have set your cascade policies. If you have set it to CASCADE_TYPE ALL, then theoretically it should persists.

But in any case, it is better to wire up both sides of a relationship when you are trying to persist associations.